# Modify texture of sepcific area of Terrain in unity

Tags: textures, unity, terrain

I am developing a farming simulator 3D game in unity. I have a crop field on terrain which is actually a texture paint in square to show a crop area, and i have to perform sowing (prepare field for seeding) in which process as tractor pass on that texture part its texture from plain soil which i had applied on it should change to more darker and rough texture. I have a idea to get that specific texture part from terrain data but i do not understand how to modify that specific area's texture at run time (through code). Any help would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some descriptive images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get all the textures used for whole terrain. From those you can get the texture you want to modify or change.

Use `TerrainData.splatPrototypes`to get textures. Then change the color properties to give it a darker look or change  the texture.